Show that all Mobius transformations that map the unit disc to itself is of the form $e^{\lambda i}(z-a)/(\overline{a}z-1)$
Let $a$ be such that $|a|<1$. Let $\phi_a(z) = (z-a)/(\overline{a}z-1)$. Show that $\phi_a$ maps $D(0,1)$ one-to-one onto itself and that it is its own inverse. Show in addition that every Mobius transformation mapping $D(0,1)$ onto itself is of the form $e^{\lambda i}\phi_a$, for some real constant $\lambda$ and some $a$ in $D(0,1)$. (Here $D(0,1)$ denotes the unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$.)
I have done the first part, but am stuck on the second. My attempt was to try showing that maybe $f$ will be its self inverse after some rotation, and then to show that all mobius transformation that maps $D(0,1)$ back to itself with a self inverse is of the form as $\phi_a$ for some $a$ in $D(0,1)$, but this is probably too naive to be true.
